# convert List<string> to string array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I wanted to split a json file and store its contents in an array and then print them out to the console, i have been successful in doing so except in the problem of converting List to a string array.

My code is :

```
package com.acme.datatypes;
```

public class User {

```
private List<String> authors;
private String publisher;
private String title;
private int year;

public List<String> getAuthors() {
    return this.authors;
}

public void setAuthors(List<String> authors) {
    this.authors = authors;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return this.publisher;
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getYear() {
    return this.year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
```

}

and another class :

```
package com.acme.datatypes;
```

public class UserTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {
    split("");

}

// Parsing or Reading the JSON file using external libraries
public static String split(String V) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {
    File jsonFile = new File("library.json");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<User> userList = mapper.readValue(jsonFile,
            new TypeReference<List<User>>() {
            });

    // Store the titles in an array and then print them out to the
    // console
    for (User usert : userList) {
        String[] title = new String[1];
        for (int c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
            title[c] = usert.getTitle();
            System.out.println(title[c]);
        }
    }
    // Create blank line on console
    System.out.println();

    // Store the publishers in an array and then print them out to the
    // console
    for (User userp : userList) {
        String[] publisher = new String[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            publisher[i] = userp.getPublisher();

            System.out.println(publisher[i]);
        }
    }
    // Create blank line on console
    System.out.println();

    // Store the year(for a book) in an array and then print them out to the
    // console
    for (User usery : userList) {
        int[] year = new int[1];
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            year[j] = usery.getYear();

            System.out.println(year[j]);
        }
    }
    // Create blank line on console
    System.out.println();

    ;

        return V;
    }
}
```

}

```
 My json file is : 

[
            {
                "title": "Principles of Compiler Design",
                "authors": [
                    "Aho",
                    "Ullman"
                ],
                "publisher": "Addison Wesley",
                "year": 1977
            },
            {
                "title": "Compilers: Principles Techniques and Tools",
                "authors": [
                    "Aho",
                    "Sethi",
                    "Ullman"
                ],
                "publisher": "Addison Wesley",
                "year": 1985
            }]
```

Comment: You need to learn some basic Java skills. Follow a tutorial or something. Your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: *the problem of converting List to a string array* : `list.toArray(arr[0]);`

Comment: @NoobUnChained, can you explain further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as easy as:

```
List<String> yourList = ...
String[] array = yourList.toArray(new String[yourList.size()]);
```

Can't find the part of code where you are trying to do this, or else I'd had used your variable names.

Comment: I want to convert the List<String> of the author in the User class to a string array by calling the user class in the usertest class

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that means :(

Comment: @jlordo I may be wrong but I don't think its that simple, their trying to store fields from items on the list into a string, not the entire object in an array.  I may have misread, but thats my take on it.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Okay i understood that, but how to convert the List<String> to String array?

Comment: @user2253589: You can convert the `List<String>` to `String[]` with the code in my answer.

Comment: I don't see a `List<String>` in the code you provided can you be more specific?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: That's exactly the part I do not understand.

Comment: @kevinBowersox, Yes, it is the User class, declared as "private List<String> authors;". I want to convert that into an array of String

Comment: @user2253589: Then use `String[] array = authors.toArray(new String[authors.size()]);`

Comment: If your trying to convert List<User> to List<String> use jlordo's code.  If you trying to get a List<String> for each field in User the code I provide will help.

Comment: @user2253589 Okay, so you want to convert the List<String> author to an array, then use jlordo's example.  But your still going to have issues with the other field values you put into an array given the nature of how you create that array.  Just a suggestion, next time include the exact problem in your question.

Comment: @KevinBowersox No, i only want to convert List<String> of the author variable to String.However I don't get where do you convert from List<String> to String in your code?

Comment: @user2253589 I don't do that in my solution, I just corrected the arrays you are currently making in the main method.

Comment: okay thankyou
@jlordo Can you please explain your code in a bit more detail? Because I used your "String[] array = authors.toArray(new String[authors.size()]);" and it didnt work.

Comment: @user2253589: _didnt work_ doesn't help me alot. I need the exact error message to help you. The code I provided convert's your `List<String>` to a `String[]`. Do you get a compiler error, exception at runtime or is the output different than expected?

Comment: @jlordo, I create a for loop :  for (User usera : userList) {
   String[] array = authors.toArray(new String[authors.size()]);
  } and it gave me the error author cannot be resolved.However I also used usera in place of authors, then it gave this error The method toArray(String[]) is undefined for the type User
     The method size() is undefined for the type User

Comment: This is basic Java. You need to learn about the scope of variables. The code you need is: `for (User usera : userList) { String[] array = usera.getAuthors().toArray(new String[usera.getAuthors().size()]); } `

Comment: @jlordo I get this as output : [Ljava.lang.String;@7546c1d4
[Ljava.lang.String;@785f8172 and not the author name  if i include the code and print out using "System.out.println(author);

Comment: @user2253589: Yes, that's the way arrays are printed in `System.out.println()`. Replace it with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(author));` This Q is asked almost daily here on SO. (Don't forget to `import java.util.Arrays;`)

Comment: @jlordo, thankyou it works however i still get the brackets around the author name : [Aho, Ullman]
[Aho, Sethi, Ullman]

Comment: @user2253589: Yes, that's what `Arrays.toString()` does. You are free to print the entries in your arrays manually if you have to get rid of the brackets or use `substing()` operations.

Comment: I really hope I get the accepted answer, after in fact answering 3-5 questions of yours.

Comment: @jlordo, can you help me on how to remove them?

Comment: @user2253589: Really? Replace `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(author));` with `for (String str : author) { System.out.print(str + ", "); } System.out.println();`

Answer (score 0):

The following sample can be replicated for all the places in the code where you need to put a field from the list of objects into an array.  It declares the array outside of the loop and uses the size of the list to set the size of the array.

It is important to instantiate and assign the array outside of the loop, otherwise your going to instantiate a new array during every iteration of the loop.

```
String[] titles = new String[userList.size()];
for (int x; x < userList.size(); x++) {
       titles[x] = usert.getTitle();
       System.out.println(titles[x]);
    }
}
```

**Place this code here**

// Parsing or Reading the JSON file using external libraries
public static String split(String V) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {
    File jsonFile = new File("library.json");

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<User> userList = mapper.readValue(jsonFile,
        new TypeReference<List<User>>() {
        });

// Store the titles in an array and then print them out to the
// console
String[] titles = new String[userList.size()];
for (int x; x < userList.size(); x++) {
       titles[x] = usert.getTitle();
       System.out.println(titles[x]);
    }
}
// Create blank line on console
//Rest of class...
```

Comment: @user2253589 I have added where this code should be replaced, you will need to replicate this for each array you want to create.  I'm sure you can take this example and apply it to those areas..